# How to convert dat file to readable text using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am techy102 and I want to know how to convert a dat file to readable text using python, for an upcoming project I wanted to know this information, here is my code:

```
import pickle
x = input("enter something: ")
with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(x, f, protocol=2)
with open('savefile.dat','rb') as ff:
    print(ff)
```

and it gives me this:

```
<_io.BufferedReader name='savefile.dat'>
```

Does anyone know how to actually convert the contents to readable text?

Answer (score 0):

You have to unpickle what you pickle using the `pickle.load` function.

```
import pickle
x = input("enter something: ")
with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(x, f, protocol=2)

with open('savefile.dat','rb') as ff:
    x1 = pickle.load(ff)

print(x1)
```